# How can I modify this code so that an array is made and events are added to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, calendar

I have made a simple calendar. In this calendar, I have a function called addEvent() where a user inputs an event, sets a date and that event appears in the appropriate calendar day. However, I would like to have it so that the events are inputed into an array, and that array is displayed on the calendar cell. When the code below is run, the calendar cell says "undefined"

```
for(var i =0; i<daysInMonth[currentMonth];i++)
{
 if(i == ((dateOfEvent)-1))
  {
    var events = [];
    events.push(event);
    for(var g =0; g<=events.length;g++)
    {
      text[i].innerHTML = events[g] + "<br>";
    text[i].setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible");
    }


  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you go 1 step too far in your array.  if g == events.length, then events[g] is undefined.

Of course, I think you have other problems, like you events array always getting reset to [], but you'll figure it out.